# Unix add a comma in the hundredths place and a $ to the last field

Tags: unix, sed

I have a number in the last field of my text file and I need to add a dollar sign to each line and a comma in the hundredths place of the number. So 10000 would now be $10,000.

one of the lines looks like this

```
World fair:399-454-9999:832 ponce Drive, Gary, IN 87878:3/22/62:24500
```

need it to look like this

```
World fair:399-454-9999:832 ponce Drive, Gary, IN 87878:3/22/62:$24,500
```

Comment: your example has 4 digits after the comma.

Comment: oops, sorry about that.

Comment: Stackoverflow is about helping people solve problems with their `if/else/endif` type coding problems. Its not meant to be a free coding service. You're expected to show some code that people can then help you get better at your craft. You should also indicate what is the largest number you expect in that last field. If it is always 5 digits, then the answer in trivial but1-12 digits for example will take some work, or a language with a commafying library ;-)  Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `'` `printf` format flag to get the thousands groupings.

(I can't find a good reference for it but it is in the `printf` [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) at least.)

> The SUSv2 specifies one further flag character.
>
> `'`
>
> For decimal conversion (**i**, **d**, **u**, **f**, **F**, **g**, **G**) the output is to be grouped with thousands' grouping characters if the locale information indicates any. Note that many versions of gcc(1) cannot parse this option and will issue a warning. SUSv2 does not include %'F.

Then you just need a fairly simple application of awk.

```
awk -F : -v OFS=: '{$NF="$"sprintf("%\047d", $NF)}7' file
```

- `-F :` sets the field separator to `:` so we get just the number in the final field
- `-v OFS=:` sets the output field separator to `:` so awk puts the colons back for us
- `\047` is the octal code for a single quote to embed it in the single-quoted string easily
- `7` is a truth-y value to cause awk to print the line

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you for elaborating, I am not too familiar with awk yet, but I am learning. I was trying it with sed however it took too much coding when pipelined with my other commands.

Comment: When I run the awk command, I don't see the comma ($24500).  The sprintf single-quote operator may be locale-specific.

Comment: @ChrisKoknat It is locale-specific, yes.

Comment: How to set the locale so that the comma will be printed?

Comment: @ChrisKoknat What locale are you using? What does `locale` output? I believe printf uses the non-monetary grouping character/format from the locale (if I recall what I read yesterday correctly).

Comment: `locale` reports POSIX

Comment: You can just set it on the `awk` command line instead of exporting it too. `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 awk .....`

Answer (score 1):

The Perl Cookbook offers this regex solution:

```
sub commify {
    my $text = reverse $_[0];
    $text =~ s/(\d\d\d)(?=\d)(?!\d*\.)/$1,/g;
    return scalar reverse $text;
}
```

This can be incorporated into a specific solution:

`perl -lpe 'BEGIN{sub commify {$t=reverse shift; $t=~s/(\d\d\d)(?=\d)(?!\d*\.)/$1,/g; reverse $t}} s/(\d+)$/chr(044).commify($1)/e' file`

output:

```
World fair:399-454-9999:832 ponce Drive, Gary, IN 87878:3/22/62:$24,500
```

A solution using unpack:

`perl -lpe 'BEGIN{sub commify {$b=reverse shift; @c=unpack("(A3)*", $b); reverse join ",", @c}} s/(\d+)$/chr(044).commify($1)/e' file`

If you have the Number::Format library installed, there is a shorter solution:

`perl -lpe 'BEGIN{use Number::Format "format_number"} s/(\d+)$/chr(044).format_number($1)/e' file`

All of the above solutions use Perl's `s/foo/bar/e` substitute operator with the `e` flag, which eval's the `bar` section.
`chr(044)` is used to print the `$` (otherwise it would be eval'd)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the dollar signs and the comma separately:

```
sed -i "s/:\([0-9]*\)$/:\$\1/g" file.txt
sed -i "s/\([0-9]\)\([0-9]\{3\}\)$/\1,\2/g" file.txt
sed -i "s/\([0-9]\)\([0-9]\{3\}\)\([0-9]\{3\}\)$/\1,\2,\3/" zeros.txt
```